# How do you generate a production build using Angular 1.2.6 CLI and Angular 4?

Tags: angular

Angular.io seems to have a tutorial about AOT but it's sadly incomplete (or I'm missing something).
I'm trying to generate a production build using Angular 4 and Angular CLI 1.2.6 but I don't understand what I need to run or in what order. The CLI doesn't really seem to support doing production builds.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: it's `ng build -prod`

Comment: Did you even read the documentation?

Comment: @Dgo `ng build --prod`

Comment: Turns out my problem was I followed the AOT instructions on the site. Turns out it's all in built! Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng build --prod`. The documentation is available here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng build --prod` and if you what to build with AOT you can use `ng build --prod --aot`